# How can you make use of a @Binding var state change in a model object?

Tags: swiftui

I have a view with some controls for choosing a date property. I would like to use that date property in a sibling's view model to search in CoreData for a `Schedule` object for that date, or create one in case there is none - a `searchOrCreate` method. (I wished I could use `@FetchRequest` for this but I haven't yet found a way)

I've made the date a `@Binding` var so I can get the view update in the `Child2` view, but I haven't found a way to pass the state changes to its model for it to do a `searchOrCreate`, as `didSet` does not work on bindings. Am I not approaching this correctly, and should I just use an `@Environment` variable or something else?

```
struct ParentView: View {
  @State var day: Date = Date().noon
  var body: some View {
    VStack() {
      Child1View(day: $day)
      Child2View(day: day)
    }
  }
}

struct Child1View: View {
  @Binding var day: Date

  // code to select day
}

struct Child2View: View {
  var day: Date // I do not need to update the day in this view, 
  //just display it and use it in an object, so I did not use @Binding
  @StateObject private var viewModel = Child2ViewModel()

  ...
}

class Child2ViewModel: ObservableObject {
  var day: Date {
    didSet {
      // call searchOrCreate in CoreData for the Schedule object
    }

  @Published var schedule: Schedule
}
```

What I have discovered works is if I make the viewModel be a part of the parent view and pass it down, however it feels like this breaks encapsulation. Ideally I would want `Child2View` to just get a date and do its thing from there.

```
struct ParentView: View {
  @StateObject var viewModel = Child2ViewModel()
  var body: some View {
    VStack() {
      Child1View(day: $viewModel.day)
      Child2View(viewModel: viewModel)
    }
  }
}

struct Child2View: View {
  @ObservedObject private var viewModel: Child2ViewModel
  ...
}

class Child2ViewModel: ObservableObject {
  @Published var day = Date().noon {
    didSet {
      // call searchOrCreate in CoreData for the Schedule object
    }

  @Published var schedule: Schedule
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `onReceive` to capture the changes of the parent variable and pass it to the ViewModel:

```
import Combine
import SwiftUI

struct ParentView: View {
    @State var day: Date = Date()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Child1View(day: $day)
            Child2View(day: day)
        }
    }
}

struct Child2View: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = Child2ViewModel()
    var day: Date

    var body: some View {
        Text("Child2View")
            .onReceive(Just(day)) { // whenever the parent `day` changes, update the viewModel
                guard viewModel.day != $0 else { return }
                viewModel.day = $0
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it appears this enters an infinite loop? I would imagine this is because `viewModel.day` has a `didSet` which updates the `@Published schedule`, which causes `Child2View` to be redrawn and hence the `@Binding` to receive again.

Comment: @SebastianVancea Yes, `onReceive` is also fired when the view is initialised. You can add a guard statement to check if the value changes - see the updated answer.

Comment: it seems redundant that the view will be redrawn twice, once for the `day` update and once for `@Published schedule` but I guess that would not be a great issue.
However, why does the day need to be binded in `Child2View`? I don't need to do any updates on it in that view, and it looks like .onReceive gets called on it even if it's a simple var.

Comment: @SebastianVancea I didn't notice it - yes, if don't change the value, then it doesn't have to be a `@Binding`.